# How to make Ruby model find, select return integer for integer columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, let's call it "User". It has a field named "age" and it's an int

When I do:

```
user = User.find(:all, :select => "age").first
age = user.age
```

I get the age back as a string, even though it's an integer column.

I know I can easily do age.to_i to get an integer, but sometimes I forget, and it turns to a bug downstream as I end up comparing a string to an integer.

How do I make find, and select return an actual integer when the column is an int? When I use User.where, it does return an actual integer. I want User.find to behave the same exact way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting, and many other transformations on data that comes form the database, can be done by writing a method for the attribute in question, and directly accessing the attributes to transform them.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def age
    self[:age].to_i
  end
end

User.new(:age => "29").age # => 29
```

You might also want to do this when converting a string to symbol, or to use BigDecimal for currencies, for example. In some cases, writing a custom setter method will also be required.

I'm sure there's a gem out there where you could define typecasts on attributes to have these methods generated automatically for you.

Answer (score -2):

why do you use so long form?
Just try to do so:
User.first.age

Comment: That was just an example.. I'm not really using that query.

Comment: What the version of Rails do you use? IN Rails 3.2.1 all works good.

Comment: What the persons are lowering my reputation. Do it. Make yourself feel better.

Comment: It's because you have missed the point of the question. The OP isn't trying to the age of the first User, they want User.age to return an integer instead of a string.